# converting c++ class to a byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, serialization, byte

It is possible to convert the following Student class to a binary file by writing it with ios::binary

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Student{
    public:
        char name[40], address[120], gender;
        double age;
        bool is_blabla;
};

int main() {

    Student one;
    strcpy(one.name, "Cancan Can");
    strcpy(one.address, "example example exampla");
    one.gender = 'M';
    one.age = 25;
    one.is_blabla = true;

    ofstream ofs("fifthgrade.ros", ios::binary);
    ofs.write((char *)&one, sizeof(one));

    Student two;
    ifstream ifs("fifthgrade.ros", ios::binary);
    ifs.read((char *)&two, sizeof(two));

    // check if the data is OK
    cout << "Student Name: " << two.name << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

The file looks like as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU5C7.png

So how can I do the same thing to convert the class to a byte (or say char*) array in this case?

Edit: But in this case, Let's say I have a class having methods. The answers you gave is telling me to write my own bitwise operators to serialize a complex class. Can you refer to a good source teaching how it can be done or a small sample/example for it?

Edit2: I have to avoid using extra libraries because I may deserialize the serialized code on a machine/compiler that I cannot import most of the libraries (for example I will try to deserialize the code on an nvcc compiled code).

Example dummy class would be like this:

```
class Student{
    public:
        char name[40], address[120], gender;
        double age;
        bool is_blabla;

        void set_values (int,int);
        int doubleage() {return age*2;}
};
```

Comment: As said in the answers here below, just copy the data into a buffer (vector<char>, string, t hey all work fine. 
Note that all this works fine if you don't have complex types inside your class, ie. if your class is a POD (plain old data)
If you start having dynamic allocations, things get complicated and you will need to provide your own way to serialize/deserialize objects. Usually this is done by implementig operators << and >> 
In C++11 you have a is_pod method to check if your structure is a pod.

Comment: It's already complicated due to endianness and alignment. That is, watch your assumptions on how portable this serialised format would be (read: not at all).

Comment: @dau_sama, the example was a dummy one. I actually have complex classes having dynamic states and methods. So I see what you say. Can you please refer me a resource/website so that I can see how to use bitwise operators to serialize a complex class?

Comment: @cancan if you have complex classes, it's not going to be easy.
you can check http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `std::stringstream` rather than `std::ofstream`.

Then, access the `char*` using `std::stringstream::str()` (This return's a `std::string`, on which you can retrieve a `char*` using `std::string::c_str()`).

Comment: So, was it good or bad he copied the raw bytes from his student object into the stream? And what about `ios::binary` and what else he asked about?

Comment: I don't see why the produced char* could not be written to a ios:binary file.

Answer (score 2):

All objects can be accessed as their constituent `char`s, just get a pointer and cast it.

Still, even if you want to write it to a binary file (in contrast to writing a textual representation), do not just write its raw bytes:

- The object might contain a number of non-value-bits (Like padding, unused buffers, whatever). Those might contain previously recorded information, which you should not leak.
- The object might contain pointers, handles or other references to additional data. Those cannot be recovered from a bitwise-copy, as the information they indicate is the important part and won't be there.

BTW: `ios::binary` just disables translation of text-files. (Identity on Unixoids, newline-conversion on windows...)

Comment: Could you elaborate on "non value bit"? what do you mean?

Comment: _"All objects can be accessed as their constituent chars, just get a pointer and cast it."_ Isn't this dangerously misleading? It's true, but it ignores what _semantically_ constitutes an "object". i.e. you cannot serialise a `std::string` by simply casting a pointer to the "container".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And I later explain why that's not always good enough.

Comment: "non-value-bits" may also include things like vTable entries in derived classes.

Comment: @icabod: The actual vtable certainly contributes to the value, as it determines the actual type. Thus I would rather put it under hidden pointers, handles and other fun.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a more enhanced way, consider the following ways:

1. Boost.Serialization (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)
2. Google Protocol Buffers (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)