# how to use .Net 4.6.1 in unity?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, unity-game-engine

I have 4 projects that call each other, final C# project passes array to unity engine. This is all I need. 
project hierarchy is as follows: **c++ (for algorithm) -> wrapper CRL ->C# dll (to receive 'unsafe' code -> c# class in unity engine.** I think it is not the most efficient way of doing that, but everything else failed.

I tried 2 things:

1) setting frameworks 4.6.1 .NET then everything works in visual studio but when I add it in unity it automatically changes framework 4.6.1 to 3.5

2) setting frameworks to lower version (2.0)
then I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       The primary reference "**CppWrapper**" could not be resolved
>   because it has an ***indirect dependency*** on the .NET Framework
>   assembly "System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which has a higher version "4.0.0.0"
>   than the version "2.0.0.0" in the current target
>   framework.    OurFirstDL.

*I set CppWrapper to 2.0 as well but error is the same.*

Is there solution for this?

**By the way, maybe there is the other way to do what I want. I just want to pull two arrays from c++ into unity engine.**

Thank you!

Comment: There are many workarounds. One of them is to save the serialized arrays in cpp code to some place reachable by unity3d app, and read it from there.

Comment: can you give me please little more detailed explanation? It got a huge problem to me actually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527317/converting-c-class-to-a-byte-array

do you mean this technique?

Comment: this is just array of ints 10 000 number

Comment: You can just save the arrays into the binary or text (JSON?) file, and make a check in Unity3D app, if the file exists - if exists then read it from there. I am not sure what could I explain more.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski you think someone who cares about performance enough to go through c++ wants to communicate via a file? That sounds like a total disaster.

Comment: If your C++/C# surface is that simple, then use PInvoke on C# side. Unity won't get .NET 4.x in a short period of time, though the progress shoud have already started after it joins .NET Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the assembly binding tool to figure out exactly what is going on. Been a while since i used it ... Fusion logger.

Often when in these situations something will pop out.
Maybe there is something specific on the cpp side that is causing the problem.